# tracert command is not working but able to access the same site through browsers

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, firewall

**tracert** [site name] is not working in cmd prompt. But the same site has been working in all of my browsers .

Please find below output of command. I need to use this command in my batch file but there is no response received.

```
tracert google.com
```

**O/P : Response Timed out from hop1 itself...**

I have tried even **turning off firewalls & Antivirus** but no use.

Could you please clarify how to resolve this ?

Comment: Can you confirm if this issue is happening on a wired connection and wireless?

Comment: Traceroute isn't always reliable. It works by sending a series of pings to the host with an increasing TTL with each one and then tells you the host that it got to before the TTL expired. Also, if one of those hosts won't reply, you simply get nothing back.

Comment: @GeoffJackson : its wireless connection...

Comment: Are you unable to tracert any domains?

Comment: Also, what router do you have? ICMP packet handling may be disabled.

Comment: @Geoff Jackson : i am unable to do any tracert including google.com

Comment: so, how to enable ICMP packet then .. Pls tell me ?

Comment: @GeoffJackson : so, how to enable ICMP packet then .. Pls tell me ?

Comment: It depends on your router... Hence why I asked what router you have.

Comment: i am using wifi from my mobile to pc . . It was working earlier good . .

Comment: Please include full output of `tracert`.

Answer (score 1):

[`tracert`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) uses ICMP to do it's thing and the destinations might be filtering it for whatever reason.

Depending on what kind of access you have it's a bit strange that your first hop might timeout. You could try to use `ping` in order to check if you can ping the hosts you know about that are on the route. If you can't, they're likely filtering the ICMP messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- resetting the TCP/IP stack by the following: `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` Then reboot your system.

  - Or install the '[Fix it for me](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)' at Microsoft's website.
- You could also try disabling DHCP and re-enabling again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please let me know what is the actual problem ?

Comment: i have both fixit and manual cmd. but no use.. Same problem..